# Route between ip adresses on same interface

Tags: routing, linux-networking, virtual-machines

I have on my linux host several vitualbox machines and one docker machine. Docker created the default network interface docker0 with ip=172.17.0.1/16. To connect vbox machine to the docker one I've chosen "Attached to: bridged adapter, name: docker0" type on the VM configuration page and assigned static ip (172.17.0.x) to every VM. That's work fine, but... But I'd like to sniff traffic between the VM's. So I connect the wireshark to the docker0 interface and I can sniff traffic between any VM and docker container, but I can't sniff traffic between vbox hosts.

Therefore I decided create a different network for every host. I added additional ips to docker0 interface with commands:

```
ip addr add 10.0.0.1/24 dev docker0
ip addr add 10.0.1.1/24 dev docker0
ip addr add 10.0.2.1/24 dev docker0
```

and so on. And configured every VM with: ipaddr = 10.0.(0,1,2).100/24 gw: 10.0.(0,1,2).1 And every machine can ping docker container but can not ping each other. So I'd guess routing is absent between that "networks" on the same interface.

How can I enable network connection between VM's?

Comment: I don't do containers, but doesn't enabling IP forwarding help- _https://www.linode.com/docs/guides/linux-router-and-ip-forwarding/_

Comment: Definitely make sure forwarding is enabled `sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forwarding=1`

Comment: Fyi, an easier way to sniff traffic on a docker container is to just start Wireshark or tcpdump in the container network namespace, or use an image like netshoot with the `--net container:` option. Although your solution has the benefit of monitoring all 3 simultaneously

Comment: Thank you everyone for your suggestions. I solved the problem. After the docker container has started, additional virtual ethernet interface appears with name vethabcd. So all that is needed is to simply connect VM as bridge to that interface.